# ¿Cómo corregir el error R_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200?

Tags: angular, .net, .net-6.0, netcore

estoy desarrollando un proyecto a la par que aprendo angular y estoy teniendo este error al consultar mi api que esta desarrollada en .Net 6. La version de Angular es 15.2.0

Esto solo me pasa en el endpoint /Equipos/Equipos?idEquipo=
ya que para poder realizar esa consulta anteriormente se necesita anteriormente logearse y demas.
Este es el codigo de el endpoint

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Equipos")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<Equipo>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Equipos([FromQuery] int idTorneo)
    {
        try
        {
            var userClaims = HttpContext.GetIdentityClaims();
            if (userClaims == null) return BadRequest("Usuario no loguado");

            var list = await _serviceContext.Set<EquipoTorneo>()
                                                    .Include(x => x.Torneo)
                                                    .Include(x => x.Equipo)
                                                    .Where(x => x.Equipo.IdUsuario == userClaims.IdUsuario && x.Torneo.Id == idTorneo)
                                                    .Select(x => x.Equipo)
                                                    .ToListAsync();

            return Ok(list);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Y este es el codigo con el cual consulto desde la app de Angular

### Componente donde se consume el servicio

```
this.activatedRoute
.params
.pipe( switchMap(({id}) => this.equipoServide.getEquipos(id)))
.subscribe(resp => {
  this.todosLosEquipos = resp;
})
```

### Servicio donde se crea el metodo Observable

```
getEquipos(idTorneo:number): Observable<any>{



let url = `${this.path}/Equipos/Equipos?idTorneo=${idTorneo}`

return this.http.get(url);
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]